# How can i limit login on 3 devices max on Firebase at the same time

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Any idea to the best way to limit user to have max 3 sessions . If users tries to login on other device the oldest session should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there are rules likes this in firebase itself. You can do it your self. Just increase some login counter in your db in transactional style on login, decrease on logout and check the new value of counter when transaction is finished. You can detect race conditions and really limit number of logins.